# paper.js: convert stroke to path

Tags: svg, paperjs

So, I think this is a basic functionality of paper.js but fail to understand the docs or concept...
I want to convert a shape drawn with paper.js to a single SVG path. Especially, I want to convert strokes to paths.
When I draw a line with a 4px wide stroke like this:

```js
var path = new Path.Line({
    from: [10, 10],
    to: [100, 10],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});
console.log(path.exportSVG().getAttribute('d'));
```

All I get back as path is a single line `M10,10 h90`. However, what I do want to get back is a path that describes the outline of the 4px wide stroke of the path.
Something like `M10,8 h90 v4 h-90 z`.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is still an [open issue in paper.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/371), but there is an extension library that can do it for you: [paperjs-offset](https://github.com/glenzli/paperjs-offset)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
paper.setup(canvas);

const path = new paper.Path.Line({
    from: [10, 40],
    to: [100, 10],
    strokeColor: 'black',
    //strokeWidth: 4
});
//console.log(path.exportSVG().getAttribute('d'));

const strokePath = PaperOffset.offsetStroke(
    path,
    10,
    { cap: 'round' }
);
strokePath.fillColor = 'transparent';
strokePath.strokeColor = 'blue';
strokePath.strokeWidth = 1;

console.log(strokePath.exportSVG().getAttribute('d'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/paper@0.12.15/dist/paper-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/paperjs-offset@1.0.8/dist/paperjs-offset.js"></script>

<canvas width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome! Always wondered if there is a way to achieve this with paper.js
@xsrf: this answer describes a perfectly viable solution – it should be tagged as the accepted answer.

Comment: I get that the general solution (which works for arbitrary bezier curves) might be complex, but is there a simpler way not requiring an library to achieve it for simple strokes (composed of just straight line segments without any crazy angles)?

Comment: @olejorgenb - Reading the comments in that [open issue](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/371) I linked to, I suspect there is nothing built-in for those simpler cases either.